# Django Rest Framework - Possible to allow unadmin users to only change one field of the serializer and admin users to change all fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('city', 'users', 'locationName', 'locationCode')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        location = Location.objects.create(
                city = validated_data['city'],
                locationName = validated_data['locationName'],
                locationCode = validated_data['locationCode'],
        )

        return location

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        raise_errors_on_nested_writes('update', self, validated_data)
        # Only admin users are allowed to change the location name and code.
        instance.locationName = validated_data.get('locationName', instance.locationName)
        instance.locationCode = validated_data.get('locationCode', instance.locationCode)

        # All users are allowed to add themselves to the 'users' list.
        if validated_data.get('user', None):
            instance.users.add(self.request.user)

        return instance
```

What's the best way for me to achieve this? (I have commented on the code above mentioning what I want to achieve - I want only admin users to be able to change the location name and code but I want any authenticated user to be able to add themselves to the 'users' list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you may consider the logic where you are using two different serializers, depending on the current user. The decision you can make it in get_serilizer_class, based on the current user and request type (dispatch method name). As such you can separate the view logic from the serializer logic.

Working on your serializer, you may use some view context data to inspect the current user:

```python
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('city', 'users', 'locationName', 'locationCode')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        location = Location.objects.create(
                city = validated_data['city'],
                locationName = validated_data['locationName'],
                locationCode = validated_data['locationCode'],
        )

        return location

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        raise_errors_on_nested_writes('update', self, validated_data)
        # Only admin users are allowed to change the location name and code.
        if self.context['request'].user.is_staff:
            instance.locationName = validated_data.get('locationName', instance.locationName)
            instance.locationCode = validated_data.get('locationCode', instance.locationCode)

        # All users are allowed to add themselves to the 'users' list.
        if validated_data.get('user', None):
            instance.users.add(self.request.user)

        return instance
```

---

Simplifying the design, like suggested first:

```python
class AdminLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('city', 'users', 'locationName', 'locationCode')


class UserLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('city', 'users', 'locationName', 'locationCode')
        read_only_fields = ('locationName', 'locationCode')

class LocationViewSet(generics.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff or self.action == 'create':
            return AdminLocationSerializer
        else:
            return UserLocationSerializer
```

Try it. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: For the suggested solution, I want non-admin users to be able to view the locationName and locationCode as well (I want the locationName and locationCode to be serialized regardless of if the user is admin or not). I just don't want them to have write-access to the fields. You get what I'm saying? For the suggested solution, currently, if the user is not an admin, the 'locationName' and 'locationCode' fields do not get serialized to the front end so the users won't be able to view it, which will be an issue.